# (discord.py) Getting a list of all of the members in a specific voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm attempting to write a raiding bot for my raiding discord using the discord.py library in python. This scripts is supposed to be forming a list of members in the voice channel for raiding. For some reason, this script is not working. Whenever memids is printed, it just prints an empty list.

If anyone is familiar with discord.py and could tell me why this isn't working, please do. It's really troubling me and I have tried everything in my knowledge to fix it.

```
#find raiding
        voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.channels, id = '440014722587426816')

        #finds the members
        members = voice_channel.voice_members

        memids = []

        for member in members:
            memids.append(member.id)

        print(memids)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the id of the channel you can do it this way. Works for me :D

```
channel = client.get_channel(1234567890) #gets the channel you want to get the list from

members = channel.members #finds members connected to the channel

memids = [] #(list)
for member in members:
    memids.append(member.id)

print(memids) #print info
```

Comment: Sorry but where should I try this code? I wrote it in @client.event \n async def on_ready(). But doesn't show anybody in the voice channel

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work under ```on_ready()```, but if you place it under ```on_ready()``` users have to be in the voice channel before you start the bot. You can make it into a loop, convert it into command, or use another event reference to fit it into your code.

Comment: Really late comment, but if anyone else can't see any users this might be caused by disabled **[intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents)** in your [Discord app](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and code. In this case, if I remember correctly you have to enable **members intent**.

Comment: doesnt work.  use keys.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. `voice_channel.members` would return either empty or incomplete lists some times.

The docs say:

> `voice_states`
> Returns a mapping of member IDs who have voice states in this channel.
> Note: This function is intentionally low level to replace `members` when the member cache is unavailable.
> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel

I guess the `members` can't be trusted to return accurate connected member list consistently.

I solved this problem with the following code:

```
member_ids = voice_channel.voice_states.keys()
```

Comment: Intents are now implemented in Discord API, so you will have to be mindful of that if you cannot see members sometimes. Source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#v1-5-0

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT:
If your bot tracks server members or downloads the entire member list, you may need the server members intent to receive member events and the member list." on the discord developer page on the bot tab.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to go on from your question. I believe your problem is that the `id` that you provided to `utils.get(...)` isn't the correct id of the voice channel. This is probably the reason to why you're always getting an empty list.

> [`voice_members`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel.voice_members)
>
> A list of `Members` that are currently inside this voice
>   channel. If `type` is not `ChannelType.voice` then **this is always an empty
>   array**.

If you're not fully sure about the voice channel's actual `id`, I suggest you search by the name and type (`discord.ChannelType.voice`):

```
voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.channels, name="channelname", type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
```

Comment: I'll try searching for the channel that way instead and get back to you. It's just odd, because the code that I posted above worked for a few runs of the command but then broke after a while and hasn't worked properly since. I can edit the original post with the rest of the code if you think it'd help.

Answer (score 0):

I you know the channel id, I suggest using

```
voice_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
```

instead ([documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)). If you're using [discord.py-rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/), you can also use:

```
voice_client = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
```

if the channel you're looking for is in the context guild ([documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)).