# get a list of members in a vc discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried all the codes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084002/discord-py-getting-a-list-of-all-of-the-members-in-a-specific-voice-channel)

but it doesn't seem to work the code I have currently is this can you help me?
[if is it possible can you even make it that pings the member?]

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, name):
  ce_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.channels, name=name,type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
  lel = ce_channel.members
  for member in lel:
   await ctx.send(member.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate through the guild Voice Channels instead of all the channels, you won't need to specify the channel type:

```py
@client.command()
async def get_vcmembers(ctx, name):
    vchannel = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=name
    )
    for mem in vchannel.members:
        await ctx.channel.send(member.mention)
```

The [`member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention) attribute is a string which allows you to mention (ping) the member.