# Discord.py - How can I get the amount of all members who are in a voicechannel with my bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a music bot and I want to know how many people are listening to the music.
How can I do this? I searched for like 2 hours and found nothing :/

What I tried so far:

```
vc = client.voice_clients
        channel = '\n'.join(channels.channel for channels in vc)
        discord_listeners = int(channel.members)
```

Error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'members'
```

Comment: Is this helping you? [(discord.py) Getting a list of all of the members in a specific voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084002/discord-py-getting-a-list-of-all-of-the-members-in-a-specific-voice-channel)? You can then just get the `len` of your list, if you create one.

Comment: I need the list of all members from all voice channels the bot is connected to

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I don't see any code or any approaches on your part here. StackOverflow is not a "*Code this for me.*" platform. Show us what you've tried on your own so far and then we'll see.

Comment: I tried this:

```vc = client.voice_clients
        channel = '\n'.join(channels.channel for channels in vc)
        discord_listeners = int(channel.members)```

but doesnt work

Comment: Please add that to your question, it is unreadable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to know that try with:

```
vc = client.voice_clients
for channels in vc:
  print(f"the channel {channels.channel.name} has {len(channels.channel.members)} members")
```

or like this

Comment: Doesnt work :/
```'str' object has no attribute 'members'```

Comment: @Velix I replied before the update, has no sense create channel var as string. if you want see the members for channel you must check channels.channel.members