# How do I define the attribute for 'get_member' with discord.py

Tags: python, attributes, discord.py

I am attempting to code a discord bot that will move multiple users that are already in a voice channel through an array of voice channels with one command, this is day two of utilizing python so I am definitely missing key knowledge.

```
import json
import discord
import requests
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

member = client.get_member('178326748616720394', '156247530563174400', '96013123013595136', '253307143665614849')
Brazil1 = client.get_channel('817415267256500226')
Brazil2 = client.get_channel('820528316468559892')
Brazil3 = client.get_channel('847980697658458113')
Brazil4 = client.get_channel('867262779139948575')

member1 = client.get_member('178326748616720394')
member2 = client.get_member('156247530563174400')
member3 = client.get_member('96013123013595136')
member4 = client.get_member('253307143665614849')


async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('!timetogroove'):
        await member.move_to(Brazil1)
```

I am prompted with the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File line 50, in 
member = client.get_member('178326748616720394', '156247530563174400', '96013123013595136', '253307143665614849')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_member'

It is my first time posting so any guidance towards future projects and future posting on stack overflow is welcomed

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662786/15170242) might help you

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to stack Moose!

You can use `client.get_user` or `guild.get_member` to get what you want. In this case(using in a server) I'll suggest you using `guild.get_member` (Note: you may need to set the [Intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Client.intents) in your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), if your bot is used in over 100 server, you may need a discord white-list)

You may want to use `Guild.get_channel` instead of `Client.get_channel` too.

Here's a sample of how to use it, try fetch `move_to` youself :)

```
    async def move(message): # context or message are fine!
        guild = message.guild
        member_signed_ids = [178326748616720394, 156247530563174400, 96013123013595136, 253307143665614849]
        for member_signed_id in member_signed_ids:
            member = guild.get_member(member_signed_id)
            if member:    # ensure we find it
                # if target_member.id = member.id
                    # move the member
                    # pass
```

Comment: since `get_member` uses cache sometimes the member is not in cache, then use `await guild.fetch_member(ID)` which will make a request fetching the member. always make fetch the second option under `if not member: member = await guild.fetch_member(member_signed_id)`