# How to extract user info of all members of discord via discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am asking a question here for the first time so do guide me. I've started dabbling in discord.py for a server. I primarily need only a list of all members on a discord server.

My entire code:

```py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('GC_TEST_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('GC_TEST_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
    )

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
    )

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Also, if you can help me get the online\offline status of the members it would be very helpful. Researched on it and I'm not sure if it is possible with a list. I am a complete beginner so pardon me if there are some dumb mistakes.

Comment: Do you want user info to be separated by guild? And is server the same as channel?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use `client.run(TOKEN)` twice. Place it once, at the end of your code.
2. I would suggest checking for `guild.id` instead of `guild.name` because the name of your server can change.
3. If you are using `os.getenv` you don't have to import and use `dotenv`.
4. If you want to print members from all servers your bot is in then remove the line: `if guild.name == GUILD:`. Otherwise, it will print members only from the `GUILD`.

```py
import os   
import discord

TOKEN = os.getenv('GC_TEST_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('GC_TEST_GUILD')

# enabling intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:

            print(
                f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
                f'{guild.name}\n'
            )

            members = '\n - '.join([f"{member.name} ({member.status})" for member in guild.members])
            print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

***Remember to enable [`intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.members) and [`intents.presence`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.presences)!***

Comment: How to enable intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents

Comment: You don't need to enable presences for something like this.

Comment: @Timi if you want to get members' status (online/offline) you have to. Otherwise it will always print offline.

Comment: Thanks @RiveN. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
channel = client.get_channel(1234567890) #gets the channel you want to get the list from

members = channel.members #finds members connected to the channel

memids = [] #(list)
memstatus = []

for member in members:
    memids.append(member.id)
    memstatus.append(member.status)

print(memids) #print info
```

**Reference:** [(discord.py) Getting a list of all of the members in a specific voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084002/discord-py-getting-a-list-of-all-of-the-members-in-a-specific-voice-channel)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer with help of the people here. The code is:

```
import os
import discord

TOKEN = os.getenv('GC_TEST_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('GC_TEST_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:

          print(
            f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
          f'{guild.name}\n'
          )

    members = '\n - '.join([f"{member.name} ({member.status})" for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer to let others know that your question was answered instead of pasting it as another answer.