# Count the number of people in a voice channel based on the roles they have

Tags: python, discord, bots

I would like to know how to make my BOT Discord count the number of people in a voice channel and who have a certain role and display it with for example the command !vocal, in the image for example, Versus is a role and next to it we see the number of people with this role who are in the vocal at a time T, I don't know where to start to do this for about forty roles, can you help me Please ?
(in python)
[Image for an example of what i'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRUaz.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question by adding the program or code block you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the things that you need to do. [(discord.py) Getting a list of all of the members in a specific voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084002/discord-py-getting-a-list-of-all-of-the-members-in-a-specific-voice-channel) This link tells you how to get all the users from a voice channel then after you do this you would need to create a list and put all the users in that list. Then after that, you would need to put that list in an embed.